# How to display all records in one page in crystal reports while using multiple detail section?

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, subreport

In this below image i design a crystal report
[image]

the records are printing  in eight pages.i have three details section one detail section i inserted sub report.anther two detail sections i inserted two different formats 
i have written one store procedure as below.
out put is[image]

i am not getting any idea solve this problem 
please help me

Actually my problem is i have three tests in my project.i have to print three tests in three different pages with different formats In first test i have eight results i have to show eight results in one page.is there any solution give reply

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `grouping` for all the detail section. And While grouping click on the `keep group together`.
Thus your problem is solved